# What to do when you live too far from civilization?

Tags: pokemon-go

I want to get into Pokemon GO but unfortunately I live out in the middle of nowhere for the next six months. Is there any way I can make progress without having to drop cash, esp. given that I am unable to travel for my current situation?

Comment: As mentioned in [this answer](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/273565/81131), pokémon spawns are based on population density/traffic data. If you're in a small town, you should still see pokémon spawning, albeit infrequently. If you're out in an area with no proper roads or houses, you're probably out of luck.

Comment: I wish there was a way I could just fake where I was at. Do you think it might be possible to spoof my location somehow?

Comment: That is considered cheating, is bannable, and spoofing GPS makes it so you can't catch pokemon period.

Comment: @totallynotiniraq You can, but it will get you soft-banned (i.e. Once Niantic picks up on it, you won't be able to catch pokémon or receive items for a few hours). I've heard of people being hard banned for doing it often enough.  I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: RIP. Well, in the meantime what should I play to pass the time in a sandy ass bunker?

Comment: @totallynotiniraq I would love to start a "Pokemon for the Troops" initiative to help guys like you out. Every base should have a gym and PokeStop.

Comment: Since your edit didn't add anything to your question, I've rolled it back.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, if you can't move your options aren't many. I do hope Niantic releases an update to make rural playing more viable.

Answer (score 1):

If there is an interstate or other major highway nearby, try hanging out near one for a while; spawn frequency seems to correlate to cell data.  If nothing else, locations near it might have Pokestops or gyms.

Otherwise, a town center/downtown, especially one with some parks, might give you good luck.