# Are there Pokemon in areas without roads?

Tags: pokemon-go

I live in a less densely populated area, and I was thinking I could go Pokémon-hunting in the forest. There are no roads or monuments in that area, and I was wondering if there is any chance of Pokémon in an area with less landmarks and roads?

Comment: Considering lack of reports of kids lost in forests due to Pkmn, I guess answer is no. (At least not in large quantities, Poks spawn in crowded areas more often, Google Traffic api and such). Possible duplciate: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/273564/why-are-there-no-pok%C3%A9mon-near-me

Comment: When I walk 4-mile round trip to Starbucks thru a typical USA neighborhood and down an artery, even with incense, don't catch much. But at Starbucks with a theatre nearby, Pokemon are off the chart. So, hatch eggs while walking; catch Pokemon at Starbucks / theatre area.

Comment: FYI: the plural of Pokémon is Pokémon.  See here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portal:Pok%C3%A9mon

Answer (score 43):

Pokemon spawn rates are influenced by cell phone activity in a given area, so while it would make sense for pokemon to be in empty fields and forests, they actually spawn very little in those areas and are much more common in malls and retail areas that have high pedestrian traffic.

Comment: Adding my experiences to your answer -- I've been to parks with large wooded / forest areas, and all the nearby Pokemon have always been within the main part of the park, not the wooded areas (except on rare cases where they're a couple steps into the woods, but that's probably just an artifact of the spawning system).

Comment: You can technically cause pokemon to spawn based on solely your own cell phone signal, but it's such a low rate that it's much more practical to head to high density areas.

Comment: I'm just fortunate enough that my house happens to be a spawn point, but it's unfortunately just a constant stream of Pidgeys, Weedles, Rattatas, and Venonats.

Comment: I can confirm from personal expierience that you get nearly no pokemons at all from woods, field or mountains, unless there are some people living there (houses) or at least a well traveled roads (frequented by cars, not only pedestrians). I went 10 kms through a wood and spent several times in fileds or at a hill nearby, and the only pokemon i catched was at a crossing highway

Comment: This is what made me stop playing. It's just complete nonsense how the system works and how it disproportionately favors cities over rural areas... Shame for the idea :-(

Answer (score 5):

You cannot find any pokemon if there are no roads or streets nearby.
As an example, in Venice (Italy) there are no pokemon because Venice is a city which is built on the sea.
There are a lot of players in Venice, but they can only find pokemon using items which lures pokemon to you.
This is proof that pokemon spawn only near roads or streets.

Comment: Link to story about the Venice issue?

Comment: Roads themselves are not vehicles for pokemon spawning, cell activity, population, and proximity to portals are.

Comment: Mostly water type?

Comment: I am sorry I don't have any link. However, I live in Italy and people from Venice complain about this pokemon issue on social networks.

Comment: @feelinferrety here you go: https://www.change.org/p/niantic-we-want-pokémon-in-venice you can find more results with "petizione venezia pokemon" in google (in italian) or some english results with "petition venice pokemon"

Comment: @feelinferrety, here is a reddit post about the lack of pokemon in venice: https://www.reddit.com/r/pokemongo/comments/4t0orr/in_venice_italy_no_nearby_pokemon_in_the_entire/?st=ir4lgtrk&sh=ea58e44c

Comment: This is outdated: since august 2016, Venice has Pokemon. https://www.change.org/p/niantic-we-want-pok%C3%A9mon-in-venice/u/17456498

Comment: @Trish of course this is outdated, it is a post from 2016 when the game released

Answer (score -1):

I live in Venice and there are no Pokemon at all your nearby is always blank lures are the only way to catch Pokemon but the gyms and poke stops here are in the dozens

Answer (score -2):

Pokémon usually don’t spawn in rural areas. The pkmn spawn due to phone signals, which are more common in cities or on streets.