# No variety in Pokémon spawns

Tags: pokemon-go

I live in a somewhat small town, with only 60k population, but lots of Pokéstops are in the inner town. Lots of players only catch Ratata, Pidgeys and other common Pokémon, on occasion a Psyduck or Zubat spawns, but nothing else.

These are the coords you can use on [PokéVision](https://pokevision.com/) to see the Pokémon:

```
55.250619011641774, 9.48446273803711
```

Will I see better Pokémon at higher levels?

Comment: Did you mix up latitude and longitude? I don't think that you live in the ocean, do you?

Comment: @Hexaholic, yes I think is mixed up lat and long. It shows the pointer at the north of Germany

Comment: You should move imo.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why are there no Pokémon near me?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/273564/why-are-there-no-pok%c3%a9mon-near-me)

Answer (score 1):

So far, it appears that all trainers see the same Pokemon, with the exception of incense (but all incense users see the same incensed Pokemon). Your trainer level does not affect what Pokemon spawn.

However, Niantic adjusts spawn rates, and the amount of spawns depend on the amount of people playing the game in the area. So in the future, you may get better Pokemon just because.

Also, it seems that [spawns can change](https://www.reddit.com/r/TheSilphRoad/comments/4v76ux/looks_like_nests_can_change/) over time.