# How is the density of spawning Pokemon in a particular area determined?

Tags: pokemon-go

Quite simply, in Pokemon Go, how are Pokemon distributed?

From my experience, they appear to be based on the trainers in the vicinity, because there are many Pokemon and trainers at my house, but in my local town, there is nearly no Pokemon! But neither are there any Pokestops.

Are Pokemon spawns more common in highly populated areas? Are they based on the density of Pokestops? Or what about the amount of Pokemon Go trainers in the near vicinity?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why are there no Pokémon near me?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/273564/why-are-there-no-pok%c3%a9mon-near-me)

Comment: I disagree that this is a dupe. "Why are there no Pokemon spawning near me" could be due to network issues, game not being available in your area, etc. For most people, the answer to this question will also answer that question, but that doesn't make the **questions** duplicates.

Answer (score -3):

It's not really clear how the algorithm works. I know pokestops are user submitted so you can try and submit one in your town. The current known areas are the water Pokemon are near water but that is the only solid evidence known right now. Many reports of players not having ghost Pokemon in graveyards or no rock Pokemon in the mountains. There was a decent discussion on the matter a while ago [HERE](https://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/180967-pokemon-go/73999280) but that was about it in regards to public knowledge.